# Every sufficiently large positive integer is the average of $n$ distinct primes for certain $n \geq 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, average, goldbachs-conjecture

I want to generalize a stronger [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) a little bit because that might help solve it.

I was thinking:

> *For all $n \geq 2$, every sufficiently large positive integer $x \geq b_n$ is the average of $n$ distinct primes*?

Clearly this implies Goldbach's conjecture.

So, was wondering if it has already been proven for any $n\gt 2$?

I think [Terry Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6656) proved *something different* to the above, since it explicitly says *at most 5 primes*, which is algebraically not the same thing.

---

*Remark. In particular the bound $b_n \geq \dfrac{p_1 + \dots + p_n}{n}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number: $2, 3, 5, \dots $*

*Proof* of remark.  If $\dfrac{q_1 + \dots +q_n}{n} = x \lt \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i}{n}$, then cancel out the $n$ and the result follows.  The $q_i$ are some prime numbers averaging to $x$.

For example for $n = 2$, the lower bound of $x$, $b_n$ seems to be $b_n = 4$, where $\dfrac{3 + 5}{2} = 4$ shows a solution for $x = 4$.

---

Here are some small cases:

$$
n = 2: \\
\dfrac{5 + 3}{2} = 4 \\
\dfrac{7 + 3}{2} = 5 \\
\dfrac{5 + 7}{2} = 6 \\
\dfrac{11 + 3}{2} = 7 \\
\dfrac{11 + 5}{2} = 8 \\
\dfrac{11 + 7}{2} = 9 \\
\ \\
n = 3: \\
\dfrac{3 + 5 + 7}{3} = 5 \\
\dfrac{2 + 5 + 11}{3} = 6 \\
\ \\
n = 4: \\
\dfrac{3 + 5 + 7 + 13}{4} = 7\\
\vdots 
$$

We will need some SymPy Python 3.x code.  I might code it up (testing up to $x = N, n = M$), but not for a few days.  So there is some opportunity to beat me to it.

Comment: Note that by saying 'distinct' you're already imposing a condition that (a) doesn't occur anywhere in the proven results (to the best of my knowledge), and (b) is very hard to 'control for' using the methods (sieving, etc.) that are generally applied to this style of question. Without that word then the existing results will show this for all sufficiently large $n$, and the 'averaging' is largely a red herring.

Comment: The answer is [Vinogradov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem)  which follows from a strong form of the PNT in arithmetic progressions. I am quite sure for large enough $n$ there is a 3 line proof from $\pi(x) \sim x/\ln x$.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond I say it's a red herring because the statement 'every sufficiently large integer is the sum of $n$ primes' is _already_ true and immediately implies the version of your statement without distinctness. It's not clear why you feel like 'every sufficiently large multiple of $n$' would be relevant and how it would help in going from '$n$ primes' to '$n$ _unique_ primes' (which is also likely to be true but, again, incredibly hard to prove.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n$ large enough [Vinogradov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem)'s theorem gives $\sim C \frac{n^2}{\ln^3 n}$ solutions to $2n+1 = p_1+p_2+p_3$ which gives $\sim B \frac{n^3}{\ln^4 n}$ solutions to $2n = p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4$.

And the same method as Vinogradov gives $\sim A \frac{n^2}{\ln^3 n}$ solutions to $2n = 2q_1+q_2+q_3$.

> Thus we have $\sim B \frac{n^3}{\ln^4 n}$ solutions for $2n = p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4$ as the sum of **distinct primes**.

Vinogradov's theorem follows from a strong form of the PNT in arithmetic progressions. I am quite sure for large enough $k$ there is a three line proof to your $2n = \sum_{j=1}^k p_j$ distinct primes problem just from $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$.

Comment: Simple and to the point. Nice!

Comment: @reuns do we know a number $n$ such that the statement in the OP is true, or is this non-constructive?

Comment: I will select this answer if my comment is answered.

Comment: At first Vinogradov was ineffective but to prove weak Goldbach they had to make it effective so yes I think there is some known $N$

Comment: @reuns that's good to know.  Thank you!

Comment: @Steven, weak Goldbach's conjecture was proven to be true for $n \geq 7$ see : https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7748

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture it's not new, **Hardy and Littlewood** in 1923 conjectured that for a fixed $c \in \mathbb{N} \geq 2$ and large $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

The number of representations of  $n$ as the sum of $c$ primes $n=p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_c$ with $p_1 \leq p_2 \leq \cdots \leq p_c$ is given asymptotically by :

$$\left( \prod_{\text{p prime}} \dfrac{p \, \gamma_{c,p}(n)}{(p-1)^c} \right) \int_{2 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_c; n=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_c} \dfrac{dx_1 \cdots dx_c}{\log(x_1) \cdots \log(x_c)}$$

With $\gamma_{c,p}(n)$ is the number of solutions to the equation $n=q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_c \pmod p$ with $q_1,q_2,\cdots q_c \neq 0 \pmod p$

This conjecture was proven to be true for $c \geq 3$ by **Vinogradov**, but the case $c=2$ still open (Goldbach's conjecture).

In your conjecture we take $m=n \, c$.

More details : [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification)

Comment: I'm not seeing how distinct primes comes out of that.  Does it?  If it does, I will take your word for it.  Because you start out saying $p_1 \leq p_2 \leq \dots$.

Comment: The number of representations of n as the sum of c primes diverge to $+\infty > c$, then necesserly we have distincts prime numbers $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_c$ verifying $n=p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_c$